# A field with four elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Determine the additive group of the field of four elements.

My attempt:Consider $(F,+,.) $ the field of four elements.Now $0,1\in F$ as $(F,+,.) $ is a field .As it contains $4$ elements $\exists a\neq 0,1\in F$.Corresponding to $a $ we should have $-a$.This is all I have got.Is it correct?Please suggest edits  if required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This field should have characteristic $2$, which means $\alpha+\alpha=0$.  That is $-\alpha=\alpha$.  You might try $1+\alpha$ as the fourth element.